# How to hide only text inside of label but not other html elements

Tags: jquery, css

I want to hide text inside of label tag but not the input text. I want to do this without changing the html structure. I want to achieve this using css3 or even jquery

here is the html code:

```
<div class="es-field-wrap">
<label>Email*<br><input class="es_required_field es_txt_email" type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Your email address" required=""></label>
</div>
```

I tried this but with no luck

```
.es-field-wrap+label { display:none; }

.es-field-wrap > label { display: none; }
```

Comment: I mean without editing the html content. I dont have change to edit html

Comment: Do you want to hide or remove the text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This

Email*

```html
<div class="es-field-wrap">
<label>Email*<br><input class="es_required_field es_txt_email" type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Your email address" required=""></label>
</div>
```

```js
//split text to <br> tag
    var t = $(".es-field-wrap > label").html().split("<br>");
    //set secont part of test in label
    $(".es-field-wrap > label").html(t[1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="es-field-wrap">
<label>Email*<br><input class="es_required_field es_txt_email" type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Your email address" required=""></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

### CSS

A child element with `visibility: visible` is still visible within a parent with `visibility: hidden`. Or you can make label `color: transparent` but it can be revealed should the user highlight it by selecting.

BTW `.es-field-wrap+label` would have to have the label outside of `.es-field-wrap` in order to work.

Both techniques are in the Demo 1.

---

### jQuery/JavaScript

jQuery is lacking when text is concerned. JavaScript is much more capable.

```
$('.es-field-wrap label')[0]...
```

The code above is a jQuery Object being dereferenced into a plain JavaScript Object (note the `[0]`).

```
.childNodes[0].remove()
```

`.childNodes` is a plain JavaScript property that not only gets the child elements of a tag but also the text. `Email*` is actually the first child node of label hence `.childNodes[0]`. The `.remove()` method is pretty self-explanatory.

See Demo 2 for this jQuery/JavaScript statement.

#### Demo 1 - CSS Concealment

```css
.es-field-wrap label {
  visibility: hidden
}

.es-field-wrap label input {
  visibility: visible
}

.es-field-wrapA label {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="es-field-wrap">
  <label>Email*<br><input class="es_required_field es_txt_email" type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Your email address" required=""></label>
</div>

<div class="es-field-wrapA">
  <label>Email*<br><input class="es_required_field es_txt_email" type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Your email address" required=""></label>
</div>
```

#### Demo 2 - jQuery/JavaScript Removal

```js
$('.es-field-wrap label')[0].childNodes[0].remove();
```

```html
<div class="es-field-wrap">
  <label>Email*<br><input class="es_required_field es_txt_email" type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Your email address" required=""></label>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.es-field-wrap label {
  font-size:   0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use the CSS **opacity** property:

```
label {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Check more on the w3 site about the property: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp

Comment: that changes even the input text element.  I want to remove the text "Email *" here

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="es-field-wrap">
            <label>Email*<br><input class="es_required_field es_txt_email" type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Your email address" required=""></label>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //split text to <br> tag
        var t = $(".es-field-wrap > label").html().split("<br>");
        //set secont part of test in label
        $(".es-field-wrap > label").html(t[1]);

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Not working. That removed input type text. I want to remove just "Email *"

Comment: also add jqueymin.js library in html